# App force close when reading ScannCallback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I tried to read available beacons in the area.below API level 21 i have use `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` and above 21 I have use `ScanCallback`

when I run my app on Kitkat it's scaned beacon. But when I run my app on Lollipop,it has force close and showing this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.abc.com.mybeacon.Beacon$2
```

'Beacon' is my activity class

**This is my code:**

```
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                //JellyBean/Kitkat
               mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                //lollipop+
                mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult   result) {


                 processResult(result);
                    }
              };
               startScan();
            }

     }

     private void startScan() {
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
        }

     private void stopScan() {
           mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
        private void processResult(ScanResult result) {

            Log.d("res"," "+result.getDevice().getName().toString());
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between when it works and when it does not work?

Comment: I have test this app on kitkat.when withing 'mScanCallback' app crashed.without 'mScanCallback' app is working.but i want 'mScanCallback' for sdk>21 devices to scan beacon

Answer (score 0):

You try to instantiate the ScanCallback on devices with Kitkat and lower, but they don't know the ScanCallback class, as it was added in Lollipop.
I suggest to instantiate the ScanCallback in the onCreate method, there you can check if the device is running Lollipop or newer.

Edit: Just for clarification, this does fail with the same error or do you get another error?

```
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                //JellyBean/Kitkat
               mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                //lollipop+
                mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                    }
               };
               startScan();
            }

     }

     private void startScan() {
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
     }

     private void processResult(ScanResult result) {
            Log.d("res"," "+result.getDevice().getName().toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: but i have a check in Oncreate.it's checking lower than lollipop and direct to method.also i have check ScanCallback in Oncreate.not working.same error

Comment: You use a static initialisation for your ScanCallback, it will try to initialise it, as soon as your class is initialised. Just declare the ScanCallback and initialise it in the onCreate method, if the OS is Lollipop or higher

Comment: I edited my answer in case there was a misunderstanding

Comment: So you still get a NoClassDefFoundError? Is there more code in your class, because I don't see anything which could lead to that error.